# Wrapped gifts distribution to correct child Probability question

Tags: probability

Three different gifts were bought to be distributed to three children. Each gift box was labeled with the recipient’s name. Unfortunately, the gifts were later wrapped, covering the labels. If each child is given one of the three gifts at random to open, what is the probability that no child opens a gift labeled with his or her name? Express your answer as a common fraction

I want to solve this probability question with complementary counting; the probability that each person gets their gifts is 1/3 * 1/2 * 1/1, which is 1/6. Then, can't you do 1 - 1/6, which gives you 5/6. However, the real answer is 1/3. Why?

Comment: The complimentary event is "at least one child gets their own gift"  not "every child gets their own gift".

Comment: Oh right! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

An arrangement in which no element is in its proper place is called a [derangement](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html)

For a derangement of $3$ elements, it is obvious by trial and error that out of the $6$ permutations of the "proper" order $ABC$, there are only $2$ derangements, $BCA$ and $CAB$, yielding $Pr = \frac 1 3$

For larger problems, a useful formula you can carry for the number of derangements is

D(n) = $[\frac {n!} e]$ where $[\; ]$ represents the nearest integer function.

Thus number of derangements of $ABCDEF$ will be $[\frac {6!} e] = 265$